# Magento2.3.2: Cache is not writable error

Tags: cache, magento2.3.2

Suddenly I am getting the following error on my website : [Depoto](https://www.depoto.com/).

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache/" is not writable in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180):
>   Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/opt...') #1
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87):
>   Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/opt/bitnami/ap...') #2
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...',
>   Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /opt/bitnami in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php
>   on line 209

Answer (score 1):

> "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache/" is not writable in
>
> /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
>   Stack trace: #0

Looks like you got problem with permissions.

Refer [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)

and remeber to run that as web server user :)

like:

```
www-data
```

but this would be based on your server configuration.

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara, ask your server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

it is due to the ownership issues. I was using ubuntu os so I used the following command to correct ownership.

```
sudo useradd magento
```

Now associate this magento user to the web server’s user group. In ubuntu it is by default www-data

```
sudo usermod -g www-data magento
```

Now navigate the Magento project directory in the terminal and run following commands.

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; 

 sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;   

 sudo chown -R magento:www-data . 

 sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Once these commands run successfully then magento user have all required permission whatever Magento setup needed.

Restart the apache server by the following command

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Answer (score -1):

Go to Magento root directory using below command

> cd /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs

And run below commands

> chmod -R 777 var/ pub/

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: 777 allows EVERY user to access these folders and data inside. This is a security risk and can leak important stuff. Especially if you are on a shared hoster. He has to change the owner instead.